# How to import a class inside a gradle custom task?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to use [this](http://willis7.github.io/blog/2013/gradle-output-to-log.html) excerpt of code to intercept gradle logs into a file. I don't want to polute my `build.gradle`, therefore, I've created an `interceptor.gradle` to encapsulate this logic. It looks like that:

**`interceptor.gradle`**

```
import org.gradle.logging.internal.*

task intercept {
    def outputStream = new File("gradle.log")
        gradle.services.get(LoggingOutputInternal).addStandardOutputListener (new StandardOutputListener () {
                void onOutput(CharSequence output) {
                    outputStream << output
                }
            }
        )
}
```

And in my `build.gradle`, I've added:

`apply from: project.file('tooling/gradle/interceptor.gradle')`

The problem is: when I try to `./gradlew build` I get:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not get unknown property 'LoggingOutputInternal' for task ':intercept' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

How can I isolate the code that intercepts gradle logs and save it into a file in a separate gradle script and make it get executed from main `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this import `import org.gradle.internal.logging.*`

```
import org.gradle.internal.logging.*

task intercept {
    def outputStream = new File("gradle.log")
        gradle.services.get(LoggingOutputInternal).addStandardOutputListener (new StandardOutputListener () {
                void onOutput(CharSequence output) {
                    outputStream << output
                }
            }
        )
}
```